# SVM classifier unexpected result without cost

Tags: machine-learning, classification, pca, svm

I am new to SVM , and I was playing with a random data which I got by simulation. I have a bivariate data like this

[image]

Data : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/190aiCNyHXrBGwHP9UleDStNXO_9NIvlNKRQ39_a9V-Y/edit?usp=sharing

I have to separate the red and yellow points. By trial and error I found that a separation exists. (The black line in the middle is a circle at radius 0.9 that separates the red and yellow, although it may not be the best one)

I applied the transformation $ x3 = x1^2+x2^2 $ to introduce a 3rd axis in order to apply a linear separator. You can see that even in 3D, a plane can be found that separates the blue and red points

[image]

Here is the code that I used

```
mod = e1071::svm(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3, data = x, kernel = "linear",scale = FALSE)
w <- t(mod$coefs) %*% mod$SV
slope_1 <- c(-w[1]/w[3],-w[2]/w[3])
intercept_1 <- mod$rho/w[3]
slope_1
intercept_1
```

And using the results from R, the plane of separation is obtained as

$z = 0.2274170x -0.2404045y+0.8795599$

which is a slanted plane as below:

[image]

We can see that this plane causes couple of misclassifications and is way too slanted (has slope along x and y axis)

If I give **cost argument** as 20 in the `svm( )` function

```
 mod = e1071::svm(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3, data = x, kernel = "linear",scale = FALSE, cost=20)
```

I get the surface:

$z = 0.018550588x -0.002184182y + 0.8475362$

Which perfectly separates both regions. This new surface is almost parallel to xy plane as has no misclassifications.
So why did R not give a better surface that separates both reigons without the cost function even though a plane could be determined without any misclassification?

Comment: Shouldn’t some kind of kernel trick take care of this? You shouldn’t have to engineer the third feature.

Comment: @Dave I understand your point but I was trying to understand this technique in deep. I feel like blindly passing some kernel function causes a disconnect in the understanding of what is happening in the backend.